# Fortify Scan issue (XSS) Cross site scripting Reflected - method sends unvalidated data to webbrowser

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, xss, fortify

I am getting the Fortify error which says that Method sends unvalidated data to a web browser which can result browser executing malicious code.
This is a java web application using spring framework.
Controller class :

```
public class Controller {

            @Autowired
            public Server server;

            @Autowired
            public Service xxxservice;

            @RequestMapping("\path1\serverId\")
            @ResponseBody
            public String openFile(....) {
            List<FilePath> filePath= getFilePaths(server, form.getPaths.values);
            FileResultResponse response = xxxservice.openFile(server, getAbsolutePath(filePath);
            String jsonOutput = getOutput(response,filePath);
            return jsonOutput;
```

Server.java

```
class Server {

String serverName;
String serverDescription;
int serverId;
String serverAddress;
List<String> rootDirectories;

public void setServerName() {
this.serverName = serverName;
```

All the setter methods are available for the above class.

The report throws the error at getOutput method line saying that server.setName, server.setRootDirectories, etc should be validated before sending data to web browser.
The server values are set through some initialization method inside getFilePaths() method as below

```
public void initialization(server,root) {
this.server=server;
this.root=root;
```

How these server values should be validated to rectify the Fortify scan issue ?

Comment: I'm facing similar issue too. I tried using Jsoup. But it is changing the byte array. Will post an answer if I find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not dealing with byte arrays as in my case , probably you could try using

`Jsoup.clean(filePath,Whitelist.basic());`

This solved most of my issues except for the case where I need to write pdf from a byte array.